Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::getColumns()
`C:\xampp\htdocs\crud>php artisan make:crud categories
Running Crud Generator ...
Creating Controller ...
Creating Model ...
Error
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::getColumns()
at C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:338
334▕         if (! $instance) {
335▕             throw new RuntimeException('A facade root has not been set.');
336▕         }
337▕
338▕         return $instance->$method(...$args);
339▕     }
340▕ }
341▕

1   C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\vendor\ibex\crud-generator\src\Commands\GeneratorCommand.php:391
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()
2   C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\vendor\ibex\crud-generator\src\Commands\GeneratorCommand.php:425
Ibex\CrudGenerator\Commands\GeneratorCommand::getColumns()`
what should i do in this case
im using Laravel Framework 9.52.16

Always write the version in Laravel questions.

Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow, small-tips, when you trying to ask on how to solve "X" problem, it's encouraged to state / inform, what you're trying to do. For example: what page / function you trying to run; what's the code that related to that?; Also, it's a must, to give us the code snippet (or if you run an artisan command like you mentioned, then, give us a full command of it).
Apart from that, judging from your initial question, seems you trying to accessing a non-existing function. Perhaps you incorrectly place your code, either X code isn't wrapped properly under X function. Cheers! :)

From what I saw in github, the ibex/crud-generator lib has these two requirements:

Laravel >= 10.x


PHP >= 8.1

Since you have the Laravel Framework v9.52.16 won't work.
